# OpenGL FBO Multiple textures

Tags: opengl, textures, fbo

I have an FBO to which I attach two textures. Then I want to bind the FBO, use the first texture as input (bind) to a shader and write to the second texture, both are attached to the FBO. I tried this using glDrawBuffer to specify GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 as draw buffer, but without success. Is this possible anyway?

**Edit**:

Here is how I try to do it:

```
GLuint tex0, tex1; // they are created elsewhere and bound to the fbo
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo );

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex0 );

glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);

// render code

glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
glReadPixels(...);
```

But the result from glReadPixels is different from what I expected. Can you see any problems here?

Answer (score 0):

The texture you're sampling in the shader should not be bound to the FBO. Just bind it using glBindTexture like a normal texture.

I believe you get undefined behavior if you have a texture simultaneously bound to a sampler and to an FBO.

Comment: -1: Incorrect. It is perfectly legal to have a texture attached to the FBO and sampled from a shader. It only becomes undefined when you're *writing* to an image you're sampling from.

Comment: Hi,

So in the end is it legal the situation above?